# How to require email on Stripe Element JS

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a payment intent with stripe element however I do need to catch email and name from customers to grant access to products after purchase, here's my code:

```
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("../create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", {
    fields: {
      billingDetails: {
        name: 'auto',
        email: 'auto',
      }
    }
  });
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}
```

the payment element is created and it gets the CC info, there options are set to auto or off, there is no option in the documentation to make the fields required, how can I still get that info on the payment intent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to configure the Payment Element itself to require details like the email.

The best way to get this functionality at the moment would likely be to disable those fields in the Payment Element, create your email field, and check that it is filled out before allowing the form to submit. You can then pass the email in to the `payment_method_data.billing_details` parameter[1]

```
const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
  //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: 'https://my-site.com/order/123/complete',
    payment_method_data: {
      billing_details: {
        email: 'test@example.com',
      }
    }
  },
});
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-payment_method_data-billing_details

Comment: thank you very much @pompey!

Comment: Booooo! Not towards you, but to stripe. Client side form validation!? Gross!!! They don't even care if it's an empty email after setting the email field to "never" on the client side. I mean customers probably aren't going to go out of their way to really jack with anything on the payment side, but COME ON! This is so irritating to me.